# Unknown provider: $compileProvider from ngRoute in Karma jasmine JS

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I want to test my angular app. Using karma

here is my config file for karma:

```
frameworks: ['jasmine'],
files: [
  'public/javascripts/angular/*.js',
  'app_client/app.js',
  'app_client/dashboard/controller/test/addfix-ctrl.spec.js'
],
```

here is my app.js:

```
(function(window,angular){

angular.module("demo-app",['ngRoute','angularUtils.directives.dirPagination','ui.bootstrap'])
.config(function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider
.when('/',{
    title:'Dashboard',
    templateUrl:'dashboard/views/dashboard-new.html',
    controller:'dashboardCtrl'
})
.when('/dashboard',{
    title:'Dashboard',
    templateUrl:'dashboard/views/dashboard-new.html',
    controller:'dashboardCtrl'
})
.when('/report',{
    title:'Report',
    templateUrl:'report/views/report.html',
    controller: 'reportCtrl'
})
.when('/admin-employee',{
    title:'Admin Employee',
    templateUrl: 'admin/views/employee.html',
    controller:'adminEmployeeCtrl'
})
.when('/admin-employee-function',{
    title:'Admin Employee Function',
    templateUrl:'admin/views/employee-function.html',
    controller:'adminEmployeeFunctionCtrl'
})
.when('/admin-worksite',{
    title:'Admin Worksite',
    templateUrl:'admin/views/worksite.html',
    controller:'adminWorksiteCtrl'
})
.when('/admin-organization',{
    title:'Admin Organization',
    templateUrl:'admin/views/organization.html',   
    controller:'adminOrganizationCtrl'
})
.when('/admin-alerts',{
    title:'Admin Alert',
    templateUrl:'admin/views/alert.html',   
    controller:'adminAlertCtrl'
})
.when('/admin-fix-areas',{
    title:'Admin Fix Area',
    templateUrl:'admin/views/fix-area.html',   
    controller:'adminFixAreaCtrl'
})
.when('/admin-fix-location',{
    title:'Admin Worksite',
    templateUrl:'admin/views/fix-location.html',   
    controller:'adminFixLocationCtrl'
})
.when('/admin-find-categories',{
    title:'Admin Worksite',
    templateUrl:'admin/views/find-category.html',   
    controller:'adminFindCategoryCtrl'
})
.when('/admin-find-types',{
    title:'Admin Worksite',
    templateUrl:'admin/views/find-type.html',   
    controller:'adminFindTypeCtrl'
})
.when('/admin-fix-categories',{
    title:'Admin Worksite',
    templateUrl:'admin/views/fix-category.html',   
    controller:'adminFixCategoryCtrl'
})
.otherwise({
    redirectTo:'/'
});
})

.run( function($location,$rootScope, $route) {
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, current, previous) {
    $rootScope.title = current.$$route.title;
    document.title = $route.current.title;
});
})
})(window,window.angular);
```

Here is my addfix-ctrl.spec.js

```
describe('app add fix ctrl test', function(){
beforeEach(module('demo-app'));
beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_){
    _$controller_('addFixCtrl',{
        $scope:scope,
    });
}));
it('test 1',function(){
    expect(scope.isopen).toEqual(true);
});
});
```

Here is my addfix controller:

```
(function(window,angular){
angular.module("demo-app")
.controller('addFixCtrl', function($scope, serviceDashboard, empService,$modalInstance, obj) {                 
...
$scope.isopen = true;
...
}); 
})(window,window.angular);
```

whenever i start karma, I got the following error message:

```
  Chrome 55.0.2883 (Windows 7 0.0.0) fifi app add fix ctrl test test 1 FAILED

    Error: Unknown provider: $compileProvider from ngRoute
        at public/javascripts/angular/angular.min.js:29:439
        at Object.c [as get] (public/javascripts/angular/angular.min.js:27:1
    42)
        at public/javascripts/angular/angular.min.js:26:138
        at Array.forEach (native)
        at n (public/javascripts/angular/angular.min.js:6:470)
        at e (public/javascripts/angular/angular.min.js:25:497)
        at public/javascripts/angular/angular.min.js:26:34
        at Array.forEach (native)
        at n (public/javascripts/angular/angular.min.js:6:470)
        at e (public/javascripts/angular/angular.min.js:25:497)
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'isopen' of undefined
        at Object.<anonymous> (app_client/dashboard/controller/test/addfix-c
    trl.spec.js:11:15)
    Chrome 55.0.2883 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.011 s
    Chrome 55.0.2883 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR  (0.077 secs
    / 0.011 secs)
```

please help me.

Comment: Please, specify which Angular version is `angular.min.js`. I would suggest to not use minified version, because it makes debugging impossible. Using router in specs is also not desirable.

Comment: i am using angular-1.5.9.min. i am not using router in *spec.js, but routing is defined in my app.js.

Comment: Make sure that you have matching versions of `angular` and `angular-mocks`. Make sure that you have all dependent modules (`angular-route`, etc) loaded. I would suggest to provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and replicate the problem as a plunk/fiddle. I don't think that it is not possible to resolve your issue without knowing your setup.

Comment: Thanks @estus . I found the error, my mock library version was different.